# scrollTO with strings

Tags: php, jquery, scrollto

I'm trying to do a scrollTO function with my code but I keeps just popping up to the top like its not connecting to the id im telling it to go to is there something im doing wrong?.

```
<div class="a-z">
<? $a1=range("A","Z");
    foreach($a1 as $char2){
    echo "<a href='#$char2' onclick='$.scrollTo( '#$char2', 800, {easing:'elasout'} ); title='$char2'>$char2</a>";
    }?> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready('#<?php echo $char2 ?>').localScroll({
   target:'<?php echo $char2 ?>'
});
</script>
</div>
```

code updated i dont get any errors

Comment: Please show the final, generated HTML code, and any JavaScript errors you may get

Comment: I would guess that your problem is, that you use single quotes for your attributes and IN your attributes as well.  onclick='...'#$char2'...'

Answer (score 0):

```
<? $a1=range("A","Z");
    foreach($a1 as $char2){
    echo "<a href='#' onclick='$.scrollTo( \'#{$char2}\', 800, {easing:\'elasout\'} );' title='{$char2}'>{$char2}</a>";
    }?>
```

Try this one as the php variable "$char2" in single quotes is not getting its value it should be enclosed in {}  :)

Comment: i tried yours and it didnt do anything when i clicked on the button

Comment: Please make the changes i have done in the above codes to escape the single quotes in on click event. Also have a look in the html code generated in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

rahul was almost right, but you need to use escaped double quotes inside of the onclick's single quotes.  Escape them so the php parser doesn't think you are ending the 'echo' argument.

```
<? $a1=range("A","Z");
    foreach($a1 as $char2){
    echo "<a href='#' onclick='$.scrollTo( \"#{$char2}\", 800, {easing:\"elasout\"} );' title='{$char2}'>{$char2}</a>";
}?>
```

A better solution is giving all of those links a class and a custom data attribute, then using jQuery to assign a click handler:

```
<? $a1=range("A","Z");
    foreach($a1 as $char2){
    echo "<a href='#' class='linkClass' data-destination='#{$char2}' title='{$char2}'>{$char2}</a>";
}?>
```

In a script tag:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".linkClass").click( function() {
        //On a click event, get the destination data attribute, then scroll to it
        $.scrollTo( $(this).data("destination"), 800, {easing: "elasout"});
    });
});
```